# How to configure WebSphere to generate javacore whenever the amount of hang threads is higher than N?

Tags: websphere, coredump

I want to configure WebSphere to generate javacore whenever the amount of hand threads is higher than 40.

I've seen this guide :
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21448581

But it would generate a lot of "false" coredumps, because we have a few threads which should be running longer than 10 minutes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Increase default timeout
   If it would be enough for you to just extend, when the thread is considered to be hung from 10 min to e.g 20 then just define the following JVM custom property:

   ```
   com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.threshold=1200
   ```

For more details check [Configuring the hang detection policy](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/ttrb_confighangdet.html?lang=en)

2. Define custom Health policy
   If you are running on WebSphere 8.5 Network Deployment, then you can configure health policy to achieve exactly what you want. Go to the `Operational policies > Health Policies` and create new policy with the following custom condition:

   ```
   PMIMetric_FromServerStart$threadPoolModule$concurrentlyHungThreads > 40L
   ```

then add `Take threads dump` action to it and assign it to your server.

For more details about available conditions check [Custom health conditions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cwve_hconditionsubex.html?lang=en) and [Health management](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cwve_odhealth.html?lang=en)